Common Lisp Looping: How did I force the loop macro not to iterate over its input list?
I wrote the code below (INFIX-LINKING-LEAFS - the last function - is the first caller with the loop). I'm sorry if it is too much code (five functions) for the purpose of answering my question. I thought, the whole context might be necessary to identify my fallacy.
It apparently is a cumbersome approach. But I need it to comprehend the single steps of the problem. My first try contained everything in one function, and I lost orientation. Now I intend to make it very cumbersome in seperated tiny steps.
So at this moment, I am not searching for abstractions but for the reason, why my inner loop does not start. It will be an obvious mistake, but my thinking locked at the moment. (I avoid caar etc. on purpose by the way, even if I like the shorthands.)
As you might see, I thought that the inner loop would just repeat my instructions no matter what. What I realised is, as you can see, that I instructed to loop (also dolist) just once. And, actually, I'm too dull right now to get it. Could you please give me a nudge?
Thank you so very much!
This is a sample input:
((⊂ "print" ⊂ "minus" < "logo-quote" "\"3\"" > ⊃ (PRODUCT . 400) < "logo-quote"
  "\"4\"" > (SUM . 300) < "logo-quote" "\"5\"" > (PRODUCT . 400) < "logo-quote"
  "\"9\"" > (SUM . 300) ⊂ "minus" < "logo-quote" "\"2\"" > (QUOTIENT . 400) <
  "logo-quote" "\"4\"" > (POWER . 500) < "logo-quote" "\"8\"" > (SUM . 300) <
  "logo-quote" "\"1\"" >))

If this "pre-Logo-line" is too confusing, maybe the starting datum is helpful as an information:
(defparameter *infix-case-4* "print - 3 * 4 + 5 * 9 - 2 / 4 ^ 8 + 1")

This is the code:
(defun infix-pos (lines-lst)
  "Takes a list of pre-Logo lines as input and returns a nested list 
with a sublist of dotted pairs for each line with (<position> . <weight>), 
sorted by <weight>."
  (let ((loop-ctr -1)
        (infix-pos-weight-lst '())
        (interim '())
        (out '()))
    (loop for line in lines-lst do
      (loop for el in line
            do (incf loop-ctr)
            if (consp el)
              do (progn
                   (push (cons loop-ctr (rest el))
                         infix-pos-weight-lst)))
      (push (nreverse infix-pos-weight-lst) interim)
      (setf infix-pos-weight-lst '()) )
    ;;interim))
    (loop for lst in interim do
      (push (sort lst
                  #'(lambda (x y)
                      (> (rest x) (rest y))))
            out))
    out))

(let ((new-line '())
      (pos-lst '()))
                          ;; pos-s: start, pos-o: operator, pos-e: end
  (defun splice-in-new-line (pos-s pos-o pos-e)
    "Concatenates the first part of NEW-LINE with the 'new part' and 
the last part of NEW-LINE. The 'new part' is the prefixed Logo expression."
    (setf new-line (append 
                     (subseq new-line 0 pos-s) ;; first part of NEW-LINE
                     (list '⊂                  ;; new part for NEW-LINE
                           (string
                            (first (nth (first (first pos-lst))
                                        new-line))))
                     (subseq new-line pos-s pos-o)
                     (subseq new-line (1+ pos-o) pos-e)
                     '(⊃)
                     (subseq new-line pos-e)));) ;; Last part of NEW-LINE
    (terpri) (princ "splice-in...: ") (print new-line) (terpri))
  
  (defun determine-case ()
    "Returns the name of the context of the infix operator. 
Simply an intermediate step for me, to be more easy on my eyes."
    (cond (;; (case 1:) Operator connects two plain words
           (and (eq '< (nth (- (first (first pos-lst)) 4) new-line))  
                (eq '> (nth (+ (first (first pos-lst)) 4) new-line)))
           'plain-plain)                   
          (;; (case 2:) Operator connects a plain word and a thing or (- number)
           (and (eq '< (nth (- (first (first pos-lst)) 4) new-line))  
                (eq '⊃ (nth (+ (first (first pos-lst)) 7) new-line)))
           'plain-thing)
          (;; (case 3:) Op. connects a thing or (- number) and a plain word
           (and (eq '⊂ (nth (- (first (first pos-lst)) 7) new-line))  
                (eq '> (nth (+ (first (first pos-lst)) 4) new-line)))
           'thing-plain)
          (;; (case 4:) Operator connects two things or (- numbers)
           (and (eq '⊂ (nth (- (first (first pos-lst)) 7) new-line))
                (eq '⊃ (nth (+ (first (first pos-lst)) 7) new-line)))
           'thing-thing)
          (;; (fallback:) Do nothing in different contexts.
           t nil)))

  (defun handle-case (branch)
    "Calls SPLICE-IN-NEW-LINE with the relevant crop marks."
    (case branch
      ((plain-plain) (format t "~%handle case 1")
                     (splice-in-new-line
                      (- (first (first pos-lst)) 4)
                      (first (first pos-lst))
                      (+ (first (first pos-lst)) 5)))
      
    ((plain-thing)   (format t "~%handle case 2")
                     (splice-in-new-line
                      (- (first (first pos-lst)) 4)
                      (first (first pos-lst))
                      (+ (first (first pos-lst)) 8)))
      
    ((thing-plain)   (format t "~%handle case 3")
                     (splice-in-new-line
                      (- (first (first pos-lst)) 7)
                      (first (first pos-lst))
                      (+ (first (first pos-lst)) 5)))
       
    ((thing-thing)  (format t "~%handle case 4")
                    (splice-in-new-line
                     (- (first (first pos-lst)) 7)
                     (first (first pos-lst))
                     (+ (first (first pos-lst)) 8)))
       
    (otherwise      (format t "~%otherwise")
                    nil))
    (setf pos-lst (rest pos-lst));)
    (format t "~%pos-lst: ~a" pos-lst))
  
  (defun infix-linking-leafs (lines-lst)
    "Takes a list of pre-Logo lines as input. Any infix operator that links 
two plain numeric words, negated numeric words or 'thinged' words will 
be identified. From highest to lowest weight, these partial infix expressions 
will be reformulated as prefixed expressions spliced into the original line. 
If words are bound by one operator they are lost for the next operator in 
the weight order."
    (let ((infix-pos-lst (infix-pos lines-lst))
          (out '())
          (ct-outer 0)
          (ct-inner 0))
      (loop for line in lines-lst do
        (progn
          (setf new-line line)
          (format t "outer: ~d~%NEW-LINE: ~a~%" (incf ct-outer) new-line)
          (loop for subl in infix-pos-lst do
            (progn
              (format t "inner: ~d~%SUBL: ~a~%" (incf ct-inner) subl)
              (when (= ct-inner 1)
                (setf pos-lst subl))
              (format t "POS-LST: ~a~%" pos-lst)
              (handle-case (determine-case)))        ) ; end inner LOOP
          (format t "~%outer: ~d~%NEW-LINE: ~a~%" ct-outer new-line)
          (push new-line out)
          (setf new-line '())       )) ; end outer PROGN, outer LOOP
      (nreverse out))))

The sample output:
outer: 1
NEW-LINE: (⊂ print ⊂ minus < logo-quote "3" > ⊃ (PRODUCT . 400) < logo-quote
           "4" > (SUM . 300) < logo-quote "5" > (PRODUCT . 400) < logo-quote
           "9" > (SUM . 300) ⊂ minus < logo-quote "2" > (QUOTIENT . 400) <
           logo-quote "4" > (POWER . 500) < logo-quote "8" > (SUM . 300) <
           logo-quote "1" >)
inner: 1
SUBL: ((36 . 500) (9 . 400) (19 . 400) (31 . 400) (14 . 300) (24 . 300)
       (41 . 300))
POS-LST: ((36 . 500) (9 . 400) (19 . 400) (31 . 400) (14 . 300) (24 . 300)
          (41 . 300))

handle case 1
splice-in...: 
(⊂ "print" ⊂ "minus" < "logo-quote" "\"3\"" > ⊃ (PRODUCT . 400) < "logo-quote"
 "\"4\"" > (SUM . 300) < "logo-quote" "\"5\"" > (PRODUCT . 400) < "logo-quote"
 "\"9\"" > (SUM . 300) ⊂ "minus" < "logo-quote" "\"2\"" > (QUOTIENT . 400) ⊂
 "POWER" < "logo-quote" "\"4\"" > < "logo-quote" "\"8\"" > ⊃ (SUM . 300) <
 "logo-quote" "\"1\"" >) 

pos-lst: ((9 . 400) (19 . 400) (31 . 400) (14 . 300) (24 . 300) (41 . 300))
outer: 1
NEW-LINE: (⊂ print ⊂ minus < logo-quote "3" > ⊃ (PRODUCT . 400) < logo-quote
           "4" > (SUM . 300) < logo-quote "5" > (PRODUCT . 400) < logo-quote
           "9" > (SUM . 300) ⊂ minus < logo-quote "2" > (QUOTIENT . 400) ⊂
           POWER < logo-quote "4" > < logo-quote "8" > ⊃ (SUM . 300) <
           logo-quote "1" >)
((⊂ "print" ⊂ "minus" < "logo-quote" "\"3\"" > ⊃ (PRODUCT . 400) < "logo-quote"
  "\"4\"" > (SUM . 300) < "logo-quote" "\"5\"" > (PRODUCT . 400) < "logo-quote"
  "\"9\"" > (SUM . 300) ⊂ "minus" < "logo-quote" "\"2\"" > (QUOTIENT . 400) ⊂
  "POWER" < "logo-quote" "\"4\"" > < "logo-quote" "\"8\"" > ⊃ (SUM . 300) <
  "logo-quote" "\"1\"" >))


I see ... I need to step a loop further down.

If you found the solution, put it in an Answer below, don't add "Solved" to the title. If the question is no longer relevant, just delete it.

welcome. "solved" does not belong in a question's title. if someone's answer (see below) works for you, you can put a check mark on it, marking it as "accepted". if you found an answer yourself, you can post it as an answer. [tour], [ask], [answer]

Thank you for the hint with "solved" for future answers

Some feedback:
There are a lot of unneeded variables in your code. Example, I would write INFIX-POS like this:
(defun infix-pos (lines-list)
  "Takes a list of pre-Logo lines as input and returns a nested list 
with a sublist of dotted pairs for each line with (<position> . <weight>), 
sorted by <weight>."
  (loop for line in lines-list
        collect (sort (loop for el in line and loop-ctr from 0
                            when (consp el)
                              collect (cons loop-ctr (cdr el)))
                      #'> :key #'cdr)))

The above code gets rid of one LOOP and a lot of local variables.
I would also write the rest of the code without the top-level LET. The global LET with local DEFUNs is a source for errors.

Thank you very much. All of this will be a constant process for a long while.  I will already take your advice for INFIX-POS. But for now, I first want to solve the problem as naive and cumbersome as I can do it now, for learning one thing at a time.

Your suggestion is very welcome (I hope my first comment doesn't "sound' different. It's only that I thwart myself if I think too much about less noisy code, now :-)
